# Marginal R2 / Conditional R2 0.691/ 0.937 meaning for model

Tags: mixed-model

I have a suspicious output in my linear mixed model lmer() (lmer package), where I have marginal r2 of 0.69 and conditional of 0.937?
Can I use this model?

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']

Formula: PM2.5 ~ Season + Month + Day + Time + AOD + Tem + RH + WS + HPBL +  
    NDVI + (1 + AOD | Season) + (1 + Tem | Day) + (1 + RH | Day) +  
    (1 + HPBL | Month) + (1 + NDVI | Month)
   Data: AQ

REML criterion at convergence: 68911.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3077 -0.5486 -0.1141  0.4248  6.3833 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 
 Day      (Intercept) 4.299e+02 20.7337       
          RH          5.375e-02  0.2318  -0.99
 Day.1    (Intercept) 4.693e+02 21.6639       
          Tem         7.276e-01  0.8530  -1.00
 Month    (Intercept) 3.249e+02 18.0240       
          NDVI        5.718e+03 75.6183  -0.92
 Month.1  (Intercept) 3.229e+02 17.9691       
          HPBL        7.091e+01  8.4211  0.00 
 Season   (Intercept) 2.070e+02 14.3872       
          AOD         2.907e+02 17.0489  0.00 
 Residual             2.174e+02 14.7428       
Number of obs: 8329, groups:  Day, 31; Month, 12; Season, 3
```

.

```
Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.002e+02  2.473e+01  2.616e+02   8.093 2.20e-14 ***
SeasonS     -4.989e+00  2.053e+01  8.066e+03  -0.243 0.807980    
SeasonW     -2.253e+01  2.043e+01  8.036e+03  -1.103 0.270140    
Month       -9.859e+00  2.076e+00  5.585e+01  -4.749 1.47e-05 ***
Day          1.839e-01  6.539e-02  3.985e+01   2.812 0.007594 ** 
Time         1.281e-01  2.752e-02  8.102e+03   4.656 3.28e-06 ***
AOD          1.238e+01  1.000e+01  1.306e+01   1.237 0.237700    
Tem         -9.657e-01  1.906e-01  1.180e+02  -5.068 1.50e-06 ***
RH          -2.039e-01  4.938e-02  6.435e+01  -4.129 0.000107 ***
WS          -7.148e-03  4.042e-02  7.712e+03  -0.177 0.859623    
HPBL        -2.597e-02  2.431e+00  2.788e+03  -0.011 0.991477    
NDVI        -1.294e+02  3.253e+01  2.496e+02  -3.979 9.08e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) SeasnS SeasnW Month  Day    Time   AOD    Tem    RH     WS     HPBL  
SeasonS -0.428                                                                      
SeasonW -0.417  0.500                                                               
Month   -0.519  0.008 -0.005                                                        
Day      0.078 -0.017 -0.016 -0.024                                                 
Time     0.041 -0.001 -0.001 -0.027 -0.010                                          
AOD     -0.031  0.016  0.002  0.026 -0.015 -0.002                                   
Tem     -0.239  0.005  0.000  0.010  0.008 -0.187  0.008                            
RH      -0.220  0.005  0.000 -0.001 -0.001 -0.019  0.009  0.267                     
WS      -0.072  0.001 -0.001  0.101 -0.042  0.005 -0.012 -0.022 -0.014              
HPBL     0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000       
NDVI    -0.464  0.017  0.011 -0.004 -0.160 -0.002  0.013 -0.003 -0.008  0.033  0.000
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues
```